# What is the meaning of the peer IP in the output of "ip -4"?

Tags: linux, linux-networking

I've never used this command before. What does the "peer" IP in the output mean?

```
root@mininet-vm:/etc/openvpn# ip -4 a show dev tun0
33: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    inet 10.9.10.6 peer 10.9.10.5/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 1):

"Peer" is an English word which means, as the dictionary says, "one that is of equal standing with another". The Internet Protocol was designed so that all hosts on the network would be peers of each other.

In this case your computer's peer is the one it is connected to via the OpenVPN connection you set up.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the key here is that this is a `POINTOPOINT` interface.

This is why there is information about the single address on the other end of the link (referred to as `peer`) instead of broadcast information, etc.